# How to Setup A Combox , always will with same data, as a user control to be used on multiple forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have a ComboBox that I use on multiple WinForms. Instead of dropping a ComboBox on each WinForm and then filling the ComboBox with data from a DataTable on each individual WinForm, couldn't I create a User Control (ComboBox) that has the data populated already and just use that UC on my Winforms?

Below is how I fill the data for each individual combobox now. (I have a public class for the sql stuff)

The Variable SQL comes from a Class called SQLControl. the Class has all the sql connection stuff.

```
Public Sub Fillcombobox()

    sql.AddParam("@ExaminerType", 3)
    sql.ExecQuery("MyStoredProcedure")
    ComboBoxExaminer.ValueMember = "Examiner_ID"
    ComboBoxExaminer.DisplayMember = "Last_Name"
    ComboBoxExaminer.DataSource = sql.DBDT
End Sub

Private Sub MyWinform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call Fillcombobox()
End Sub
```

Comment: Sure, you could put that into a UserControl, but you have a variable there `sql` which we wouldn't know how to move around. Can you include that, and the database connection code? It may be important to know where to put it in the UserControl

Comment: just put `FillCombobox()` public in your mainform, and add the ComboBox as parameter. Then all you need to do is call `MainForm.FillCombobox(localCombobox);` on every form you need it, and your done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a small `Class Examiner`

```
Public Class Examiner
    Public Property Examiner_ID As Integer
    Public Property Last_Name As String
    Public Sub New(ID As Integer, lname As String)
        Examiner_ID = ID
        Last_Name = lname
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, when the first form loads, get the data in a list declared in a module so it can be accessed from any form in the application. Of course, you may have other things in the Module.

```
Module Module1
    Public ExaminerData As New List(Of Examiner)
End Module

Private Sub MyWinform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FillExaminerList()
    ComboBoxExaminer.ValueMember = "Examiner_ID"
    ComboBoxExaminer.DisplayMember = "Last_Name"
    ComboBoxExaminer.DataSource = ExaminerData
End Sub
```

Any other form that needs the data to fill a combo box can use `ExaminerData`. You only call `FillExaminerList` once at the beginning of the application. There is only a single hit on the database.

```
Private OPConStr As String = "Your connection string."

Private Sub FillExaminerList()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(OPConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExaminerType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 3
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim ex As New Examiner(CInt(row("Examiner_ID")), row("Last_Name").ToString)
        ExaminerData.Add(ex)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a Awesome solution..... Matter of fact, I may use the theory on other data i use throughout the solution. Thanks!